# Data not coming when old value is changed from null to other value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Select statement is not displaying data when I change value from 0 to null or vice versa.
But when I change data from 0 to 1 select statement starts displaying data.

Please find my code (query)

```
declare @tmptable TABLE (Id INT, IsVal BIT)
INSERT Into @tmptable VALUES(1,0)
--SELECT * FROM @tmptable
DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @IsVal BIT

SET @Id=1
SET @IsVal=NULL

select @Id as PrimaryKeyValue
,CAST(IsVal as VARCHAR) as OldValue,CAST(ISNULL(@IsVal,'') as VARCHAR) as NewValue
,'IsVal' AS DisplayFieldName,
CASE IsVal 
     WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' 
     WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
     END  as DisplayOldValue
,CASE  @IsVal 
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
      WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
     END  as DisplayNewValue   
from @tmptable WHERE Id =@Id and ISNULL(IsVal,'')<>ISNULL(@IsVal,'')
```

There is problem with statement :-

```
ISNULL(IsVal,'')<>ISNULL(@IsVal,'')
```

Can't figure out the change I need to make to the above statement so that my query can work as I desired. Please help.

@IsVal variable is used to set value.

Thanks

Comment: That expression is wrong to begin with. It prevents the server from using indexes on that column  What is it supposed to do? What is the type of `IsVal` and why is it compared with a *string*? Is this an attempt to create a catch-all query?

Comment: `VARCHAR` without a length probably doesn't mean what you think it means; using it is a [bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). (Not a cause of your problems, most likely, just a separate observation.)

Comment: That expression conversts nulls to empty strings, zeros and 1s to `'0'` and `'1'`. It *won't* match 0s and nulls.

Comment: Just want to compare old value with new changed value and show in select statement if both are not equal

Comment: I think you end up comparing 0 <> '', which if done as an integer comparison will be false because '' becomes 0 which in fact, equals 0. Try IsNull(IsVar,'null')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help,
I was able to resolve the issue:-

```
declare @tmptable TABLE (Id INT, IsVal BIT)
INSERT Into @tmptable VALUES(1,0)
--SELECT * FROM @tmptable
DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @IsVal BIT
declare @oldval VARCHAR(10)
SET @Id=1
SET @IsVal=null

select @oldval=isval from @tmptable WHERE Id=1
print ISNULL(@oldval,'')
print ISNULL(@IsVal,'')
--if(ISNULL(CAST(@oldval AS INT),'')<>ISNULL(CAST(@IsVal AS INT),''))
--BEGIN
PRINT '1'
select @Id as PrimaryKeyValue
,CAST(IsVal as VARCHAR(10)) as OldValue,CAST(ISNULL(@IsVal,'') as VARCHAR(10)) as NewValue
,'IsVal' AS DisplayFieldName,
CASE IsVal 
     WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' 
     WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
     END  as DisplayOldValue
,CASE  @IsVal 
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
      WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
     END  as DisplayNewValue   
from @tmptable WHERE Id =@Id and ISNULL(CAST(IsVal AS VARCHAR),'null')<>ISNULL(CAST(@IsVal AS VARCHAR),'null')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the problem is this expression: `ISNULL(IsVal,'')<>ISNULL(@IsVal,'')`

When IsVal is 0 and @IsVal is NULL, this becomes:

```
0 <> ''
```

which will compare as integers, so the '' becomes 0 and you get:

```
 0 <> 0
```

So, in your case, 0, '' and NULL will all be treated as equal. You need to choose an invalid int (maybe -1?) or cast the 0 to a varchar to do that comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a simple comparison?

```
(IsVal = @IsVal or IsVal IS NULL AND @IsVal IS NULL)
```

You may still have problems with type conversion, assuming the types are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a simple comparison?

```
(IsVal = @IsVal or IsVal IS NULL AND @IsVal IS NULL)
```

You may still have problems with type conversion, assuming the types are not compatible.

If that is the case:

```
(IsVal = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), @IsVal) or
 IsVal IS NULL AND @IsVal IS NULL
)
```

There is no need to invent special values for `isnull()` or `coalesce()`.